# jQuery - Ask user before submiting a form

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a form with 2 submit buttons.

```
<input type='submit' name='submit-form' value='Send' />
<input type='submit' class='delete' name='delete' value='Delete' />
```

And I want to ask the user, if he really wants to delete the item. I know it could be done by making the delete button a link, but I really need to do it this way.

Thanks for your time, Mike.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should look like:

```
$('input.delete').bind('click', function() {
    if(!confirm('are you sure') )
        return false;
});
```

by returning `false` from an event handler, it will trigger a `event.preventDefault` and `event.stopPropagation`.

In relation to your comment, I would go this way to have different strings for different inputs:

```
$('input').bind('click', function(e) {
    var msg;

    switch(e.className)  {
         case 'foobar': msg = 'Foo foo foo!?'; break;
         case 'yay': msg = 'yay yay yay!?'; break;
         // etc
         default: msg = 'are you sure?';
    }

    if(!confirm(msg) )
        return false;
});
```

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/ks9Ak/

Comment: wouldn't be safer using only event.preventDefault() to let the event bubble up?

Comment: This is it, thanks. Just one more question, is there a way to pass the msg for user as parametr of an function, in case I would want to use different text for another button?

Comment: @DarkThrone: I wouldn't know why this would be more 'safe'

Comment: @Mike: well, of course you can do this, but not with a function exactly. You would need to pass in the `event` object to the event handler and check for the `id` or `class`, and call a different text based on that.

Comment: If he binds another event triggering on click after the return false it would never happen because he stoped the bubbling. At least I understand it that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input.delete').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var action = confirm('do you want to delete the item?');
    if(action){
        //delete the item the way you want
    }
});
```